# Mongoose update query not working with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First I am making entries in mongodb by:

```
var device = new Device(inputDetailsJson); //device model instance

device.save(function(err) { 
                            if (err) {
                                res.send(err);
                            } else {
                                res.write('Successful');
                                res.end();
                            }

                        });
```

This is the device model:

```
// Dependencies
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Schema Definition
var deviceSchema=new Schema ({
    "deviceId":{ type : String , unique: true},
    "version":{ type : String },
    "manufacturer":{ type : String },
    "modelname":{ type : String },


});

// Model
module.exports = mongoose.model('de', deviceSchema);
```

This is the inputDetailsJson:

```
{   
            "deviceId":"3236172417",
            "version":"5.2.3",
            "manufacturer":"abc",
            "modelname":"example"
}
```

These details are getting entered correctly, but when I try to update something, it reflects no changes.

```
var device=new Device();
device.update({deviceId:"3236172417"},{modelname:"test"}
,function(err) {
if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
else{
res.write('successful');
res.end();
```

It displays 'successful' even though no changes are made in the mongodb database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var Device = require('your device model file');
Device.model.findOneAndUpdate({
       deviceId:"3236172417",
},{$set:{modelname:"test}},function(err, user) {

});
```

Comment: TypeError: Device.findOneAndUpdate is not a function

Comment: upvoted, but I have less reputation so it wont be displayed publicly

Answer (score 0):

For updating the `device` you don't need to create a new `device`, using `var device=new Device();`

you should simply update, same as you try to find a document.

```
Device.update({deviceId:"3236172417"},{modelname:"test"}
,function(err) {
if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
else{
res.write('successful');
res.end();
```